# VS2010 Intellisense: navigate signatures w/ keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

```
new XmlSerializer().
```

I typed the code above, and an Intellisense menu appears.  One of the options in the menu is the `Serialize` method.  I navigate to that using my keyboard.

Once `Serialize` is selected, a submenu appears to the right of the main Intellisense menu, showing several signatures for the `Serialize` method.

How can I navigate this signatures submenu without using my mouse?  How can I look through these signatures using my keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried using the up and down arrows on my keyboard and it seems to do the trick just fine.

Comment: My focus is on the `Serialize` option from the main Intellisense menu.  When I use my up and down arrows, I'm changing my selection in that main Intellisense menu.  How are you having your up/down arrows drive the /sub/ menu instead of the /main/ menu?

Comment: If you type the first curly brace "  (   " then the signature menu appears, from here you can use the keyboard arrows to navigate the signatures available. I don't know if there is another way I am afraid.

Comment: I understand now.  You're telling me how to navigate a signatures `menu`.  You're not telling me how to navigate a `submenu`.  This will be helpful if no one addresses my `submenu` concern.